# Accessing Remote Kernel Objects In Windows

Tags: windows, object, kernel

Is it possible to access kernel objects on remote computers? I was reading that you could access remote kernel objects by using a symbolic link to \Device\Mup\server\object but I am not sure if that would work. Thanks for the help!

---

I know this is a little odd but I was trying to access a named pipe.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the general case - Mup is the broker that chooses which remote filesystem (WebDav/SMB/NFS) to engage for a particular UNC path. What kernel objects are you trying to access specifically?

**Edit:** Named pipes are definitely doable - try the syntax:

```
\\machinename\pipe\nameofpipe
```

Keep in mind that the pipe has to be ACLed appropriately